# Advice on communication between rails front-end and scala backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scala, rest, message-queue, backend

We are developing the following setup:

A rails webapp allows users to make requests for tasks that are passed on to a Scala backend to complete, which can take up to 10 seconds or more. While this is happening, the page the user used to make the request periodically polls rails using AJAX to see if the task is complete, and if so returns the result.

From the user's point of view the request is synchronous, except their browser doesn't freeze and they get a nice spinny thing.

The input data needed by the backend is large and has a complex structure, as does the output. My initial plan was to simply have the two apps share the same DB (which will be MongoDB), so the rails app could simply write an id to a 'jobs' table which would be picked up by the scala backend running as a daemon, but the more I think about it the more I worry that there may be lots of potential gotchas in this approach.

The two things that worry me the most is the duplication of model code, in two different languages, which would need to be kept in sync, and the added complexity of dealing with this at deployment. What other possible problems should I take into account when assessing this approach?

Some other possibilities I'm looking at are 1) making the Scala backend a RESTful service or 2) implementing a message queue. However, I'm not fully convinced about either option as they will both require more development work and it seems to me that in both cases the model code is effectively duplicated anyway, either as part of the RESTful API or as a message for the message queue - am I wrong about this? If one of these options is better, what is a good way to approach it?

Comment: Scala RESTful service is the way to go imo. At least that's how the exact same problem is solved in successful projects.

Comment: Could you give some examples and explain why in an answer?

Comment: Have you considered going with JRuby and using some common lib for the model code?

Comment: I've experimented with JRuby in the past but not had brilliant results at the time - I can't remember why now - are there various gems that just don't work in JRuby?

Comment: I am absolutely flummoxed as to why someone has downvoted this. Care to explain?

Answer (score 3):

I have used several times [resque](https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque) for similar problems and Ive been always very happy with it, it gives you all you need to implement a job queue and is backed on redis. I would strongly suggest you to take a look at it

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking it expects the backend to be in Ruby too? Unfortunately Ruby is too slow for what I need to do.

Comment: You can implement the backend in whatever you want, the only thing you have to do is consume the queue, I have done it already in Jave and it was really simple. Of course is simpler if you do with a Ruby backend, but not mandatory

Comment: In fact here you have a worker implemented for scala: https://github.com/jamesgolick/scala-resque-worker . So no extra work needed

Comment: Great, thanks. Does this solve the problem of needing to share a DB though? The input and output datasets are probably too large and complex in structure to be used as job objects.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more in how big the data is? In my opinion you would have more problems using large data as parameters than using a shared database to store this parameters. Also redis has a complete mechanism to serialize objets to use them as parameters for your jobs

Comment: Roughly 100s of maps of double arrays up to a couple of thousand items long for the output, a smaller number and a complex, interlinked structure of relationships for the input.

Comment: That is big, yes, but redis allow you to store strings up to 500MB so you would be fine.... If you decide to go with redis I would recommend you to change the block sizes though, it will work better with such big records. Also check a good serializer and parser, don't go with the defaults

Answer (score 0):

Don't take me wrong, but, for this project what does Rails provide that Scala does not?

Put another way, can you do without Scala entirely and do it all in Rails? Obviously yes, but you're developing the back end in Scala for a reason, right? Now, what does Scala provide that Rails does not?

I'm not saying you should do one or the other, but maintaining duplicate code is asking for trouble/complication.

If you have a mountain of Ruby code already invested in the project, then you're committed to Rails, barring a complete Twitter-esque overhaul (doesn't sound like that's an option nor desired).

Regardless, not sure how you are going to get around the model duplication. Hitting a Mongo backend does buy you BSON result sets, which you could incorporate with [Spray](https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki), their excellent implementation of Akka, out-of-the-box REST, and JSON utilities.

Tough problem, sounds like you're caught between 2 paradigms!

Comment: The decision to stick with Rails for the front-end was due to the overhead of learning one of the scala frameworks as we don't have any experience in them. I'm not ruling it out but so far having spent a couple of hours trying and failing to get a vanilla Play! app running (using the typesafe stack) I am inclined to think it won't be anywhere as easy as Rails is.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on how you'd structure an all-Scala solution?

Comment: Coming from Rails, Scalatra will be by far the easiest to hit the ground running with (it's, of course, a Sinatra clone). You get routing out of the box, and it's easy enough to abstract the router into a base class and then have routes call Rails-style show, list, index, etc. methods in extending controllers. Scalate for the template engine (with coffeescripted-sbt and less-sbt plugins) and off to the races ;-) Play! 2.0 has gotten mixed reviews, I'm staying away for now, I don't want the kitchen sink, give me core components and I'll do the REST

Comment: but Spray is a great project for the fire-and-forget Akka Actors approach. Harder to grok than Scalatra, but for stateless REST, perhaps the best Scala landscape has to offer (yes, BlueEyes and Unfiltered as well)

Comment: Thanks. So, just for the avoidance of doubt, are you talking about still having two apps, both in scala, in which case how do they communicate, or are you suggesting having a single app in scala which also runs the background jobs?

Comment: also, based on your Scala posts, I'd say you already have the chops to do your current project entirely in Scala. See what's on offer with existing Scala microframeworks, dig around and see what fits your collective development style. Scalatra is the closest Rails correlate I have found (other than Play!, which I have chosen not to play with)

Comment: single app, all Scala. Of course if you go with Spray, then you have the option of standing up multiple Actor instances to perform various tasks. Check out Scalatra and Spray, the former gives you Rails familiarity, and the latter, built-in Actors, caching and many other bells & whistles. In the end you have to decide whether  the benefits in switching to Scala outweigh the drawbacks in staying with Rails. No man's land approach is not a winning solution, imo